# Condicionar entre dias de semana

Tags: php, date, if

Amigos, estoy realizando un programilla que lee desde una base de datos
entre que días de la semana se debe ejecutar cierto proceso.

Estoy obteniendo el día de la semana en base a `date("N")` y me entrega un número del 1-7, lo cual seria , lunes, martes, miercoles, etc.

El tema es que al hacer el `if($dia_inicio >= $dia_semana and $dia_semana <= $dia_termino)` solo funcionaría dentro de una semana, pero si eligiesen 
que los días a ejecutar serán de Sábado a Lunes por ejemplo, no me sirve.

No se me ocurre como hacerlo. Si alguien me puede aportar con alguna idea, desde ya muy agradecido.

Saludos.

Comment: Si no pones tu codigo es muy dificil ayudarte.

Comment: Tu planteamiento no se entiende. Propongo que [edites la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/167610/edit) explicando mejor lo que quieres. En estos casos un pequeño ejemplo de los datos recibidos y del resultado esperado bastarían para entender el contexto. También siempre es bueno que muestres lo que tienes hecho y dónde te falla o dónde te bloqueas. Esto es sin duda muy fácil comparando dos objetos `DateTime`, pero si no se entiende la situación es imposible responder.

Comment: Es sobre algo concreto, no sobre el programa especifico, Tengo un proceso que debe cumplir condiciones para  ejecutarse.Ej: Vigencia Tare asignada 
2018-05-21 a  2018-05-31 entre las 08:30 y 19:00 
entre los dias Lunes a jueves.

La bd tiene:
Fecha_inicio | fecha_termino | Hora_inicio| Hora_termino| dia_inicio| dia_termino
2018-05-21 | 2018-05-31| 08:30| 19:00|  Lun | Jue
El programa debe saber que si es Martes, Miercoles igualmente esta dentro de los rangos if($dia_inicio >= $dia_semana and $dia_semana <= $dia_termino)
El problema es cuando es de Jueves a Martes por ejemplo.

Comment: Para qué explicar si con mostrar tu código se explican las cosas más fácil? :D

Answer (score 0):

Podrias guardar en una lista los dias de las semana que es valido ejecutar el proceso. Luego verifica chequeando si el dia actual esta incluido dentro del listado: [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

```
<?php
$dias_de_la_semana = array(6, 7, 1); // Sabado a Lunes

if (in_array(3, $dias_de_la_semana)) // Ejecutar Miercoles?
{
    echo "Ejecutar proceso";
}
?>
```

Ahora, para obtener el array de dias de la semana, en base a dos fechas, dejare aqui un poco de pseudocodigo:

```
dia_inicial = 3 // Miercoles
dia_final = 5 // Viernes

if dia_inicial <= dia_final
    for(i = dia_inicial; i <= dia_final; i++)
        dias_de_la_semana.push(i) // insertar en el array el numero de  dia
else
    for(i = 1; i <= dia_inicial; i++)
        dias_de_la_semana.push(i) // insertar en el array el numero de  dia
    for(i = dia_final; i <= 7; i++)
        dias_de_la_semana.push(i) // insertar en el array el numero de dia
```

Comment: Entiendo lo que indicas, pero, al cliente desde un formulario le estoy dando a elegir el dia de inicio y el dia de termino. Este ingresa la opcion dentro de los 7 dias y luego hago un insert con el valor en una base de datos
La pregunta es:
Como hago para que cuando se lecciones por ejemplo 
Jueves a Martes, para insertar viernes, sabado, Domingo y Lunes?
Como le digo inserta estos dias porque estan entre medio?
Espero se entienda. Gracias!

Comment: Podrias solucionarlo con dos DropDowns, cada uno con los valores del 1 al 7. Si el inicial es menor que el valor final, por ejemplo Miercoles (**3**) a Viernes (**5**), deberias resultar con el array [**3**,4,**5**]. Si el inicial es mayor al valor final, por ejemplo Viernes (**5**) a Miercoles(3), generas 2 array, [**5**,6,7] y [1,2,**3**], y los unes para obtener el array de dias para ejecutar el proceso: [1,2,**3**,**5**,6,7] =)

Comment: entiendo lo que mencionas, de hecho asi he estado intentando hacerlo, sin embargo no logro entender como realizar dicho proceso.
para que ocurra lo que mencionas =/

Comment: @Lusagsilva e incluido pseudocodigo (porque no se en que lenguaje procesaras la configuracion del cliente) que detalla mejor la logica que mencione =)

Comment: gracias! me queda muy claro, el unico detalle lo tengo en el ultimo for, si no mal entiendo seria en caso que elija el mismo dia como inicio y termino ?

Comment: @Lusagsilva en `else` atacamos el caso en que no sea una serie de continua de dias de la misma semana, es decir, que sea una serie discontinua. Como es discontinua, tenemos que evaluar los dias en 2 `for` (uno para cada segmento de dias). El primer `for` se encarga de recolectar los dias desde el Lunes hasta el `dia_inicial`, y el segundo `for` se encarga de recolectar los dias desde el `dia_final` hasta el Domingo. El resultado deberia ser algo como [1,2,3,5,6,7], donde el unico dia que no incluimos fue el Jueves (**4**).